# Javascript querystring code issue

Tags: javascript

I am writing some javascript (not jquery, just plain javascript) to manipulate querystrings.

I currently have the following:

```
// no viewid in querystring so append as new
if (newUrl.indexOf("viewid") == -1) {
    newUrl += "?viewid=" + viewId;
}
else if (newUrl.indexOf("viewid") > -1) // there is a view id or another key e.g. there is a linkid
{
    newUrl = newUrl.replace(/viewid=\d*/i, "viewid=" + viewId);
}
```

So it appends viewid as a new querystring key otherwise it appends it (&).

What I need to do is check if a querystring value (any, e.g. "blah") is in the URL, and if so, append with `&viewid=(number)`.

If the selection in the dropdown (which calls this javascript) changes, then change the viewid (but don't append a new `viewid`).

Comment: Added a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XtWsu/) with some test cases, please edit if I'm mis-understanding your requirements !

Comment: Please see my edited answer and see if it addresses your question?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `window.location.search` to get just the query string.

Then, you could use `split('&')` to get an array of individual `key=value` pairs.

Then you could split each pair (string) into the proper object.

Then you can find the `viewid` value, change it and rebuild the query string.

The sample code here (http://jsfiddle.net/tMBpM/):

```
var locationHost = 'http://wwwdomain.com';
var locationPath = '/something';
var locationSearch = '?test=1&viewid=2';

var searches = locationSearch.replace('?', '').split('&');

for (var i in searches) {
    searches[i] = searches[i].split('=');
}

for (var j in searches) {
    if (searches[j][0] == 'viewid') {
        //we search for viewid
        console.log('old VIEWID =', searches[j][1]);
        //if we find one then we update it
        searches[j][1] = 5;
    }
}
locationSearch = "?";
for (var k in searches) {
    var separator = k == 0 ? "" : "&";
    locationSearch += separator + searches[k][0] + "=" + searches[k][1];
}

console.log(locationHost + locationPath + locationSearch);
//for production use window.location.host instead of locationHost
//and so on
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I've got my code working. It's an ASP.NET site but there's issues updating the querystring on every dropdown change.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this nifty little package called [Query String Manager](http://npmjs.com/package/qsm)
and you use it like this:

```
var qsm = require('qsm');
newUrl = qsm.add(newUrl, { viewId: 1 });
```

and this will create your viewId=1 if there is not other querystring or append it if there are other querystrings.